# Looking for explanation of Greatest Common Divisor Recursive Function

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I'm studying recursive functions, and one I came across is the greatest common divisor. I was working through a very long and complicated piece of code that was going nowhere, and when I looked up the solution, I see it's super short:

```
function gcd(num1, num2) { 
   if (num2 === 0) { 
  return num1;
}

  return gcd (num2, num1 % num2);
}
```

I'm struggling to wrap my brain around how this works in the recursive return function call.   Num2 becomes the first parameter for some reason, and how does the second parameter work? Is `num1 % num2` the new value of `num1`? How is `num2` going to get to 0? I don't see how it's value changes.

Comment: rtm: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder

Comment: If you want to make it really short: `function gcd(num1, num2){ return (num2 === 0) ? num1 :  gcd (num2, num1 % num2);}`.

Comment: And for the mathematical explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: Also, regarding your question, when you do `return gcd (num2, num1 % num2)` you're calling `gcd` with the `num1 % num2` **argument** as the `num2` **parameter**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm struggling to wrap my brain around how this works in the recursive return function call. Num2 becomes the first parameter for some reason, and how does the second parameter work? Is `num1 % num2` the new value of `num1`? How is `num2` going to get to 0? I don't see how it's value changes.

`num2` becomes the first argument to *a new function call*.  We're not changing the value of the `num1` we have, but telling JS that in the *next call*, the first parameter will get the value from what's currently in `num2`.  Similarly, we calculate the *next value* of the second parameter as `num1 % num2`.  (To understand how the math works, you might read up on the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), but the basic point is that for positive integers `a` and `b`, `gcd (a, b)` is precisely the same as `gcd (b, a % b)`.)

So now we have two new numbers to test, and we call `gcd` with these two numbers, and, crucially, when that function returns, we return its result as our own:

```js
  return gcd (num2, num1 % num2);
//^^^^^^
```

This process stops when `num2` is zero.  Then we can simply return `num1`.

We can add some logging to your function, using an additional parameter, `depth` to track the recursion depth, initializing it at first to `0`.  That could give us output like this:

```
in gcd (120, 42)
num2 <> 0
value of num1 for the next call is num2: 42
calculating value of num2 for next call: num1 % num2: 120 % 42 ==> 36
calling gcd (42, 36)
    in gcd (42, 36)
    num2 <> 0
    value of num1 for the next call is num2: 36
    calculating value of num2 for next call: num1 % num2: 42 % 36 ==> 6
    calling gcd (36, 6)
        in gcd (36, 6)
        num2 <> 0
        value of num1 for the next call is num2: 6
        calculating value of num2 for next call: num1 % num2: 36 % 6 ==> 0
        calling gcd (6, 0)
            in gcd (6, 0)
            num2 == 0
            returning 6
        returning 6
    returning 6
returning 6
```

which you can see by expanding and running this snippet:

```js
const log = (depth, s) => console .log ('    ' .repeat (depth) + s)

function gcd (num1, num2, depth = 0) {
  log (depth, `in gcd (${num1}, ${num2})`)
  if (num2 === 0) {
    log (depth, `num2 == 0`)
    log (depth, `returning ${num1}`)
    return num1
  }
  log (depth, `num2 <> 0`)
  log (depth, `value of num1 for the next call is num2: ${num2}`)
  log (depth, `calculating value of num2 for next call: num1 % num2: ${num1} % ${num2} ==> ${num1 % num2}`)
  log (depth, `calling gcd (${num2}, ${num1 % num2})`)
  const result = gcd (num2, num1 % num2, depth + 1)
  log (depth, `returning ${result}`)
  return result
} 

console .log (gcd (120, 42))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Coding each step illustrates exactly how it works.

Comment: Well, except that it was wrong.  I fixed it already.  I changed the the logging to show correctly that we're comparing `num2 == 0`.  My output was written as though we were comparing `num1 == num2`.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It might be tricky to understand without going through examples with pen and paper. `num1 % num2` becomes the new value of `num1` for each recurring call of the function.

If you try it with `gcd(14,4)`,

4 != 0, 14 % 4 = 2 then next call is `gcd(4, 2)`.

2 != 0, 4 % 2 = 0 then next call is `gcd(2, 0)`.

0 == 0 then greatest common divisor of 14 and 4 is 2. This value is returned all the way up the call stack.

Another example with `gcd(5,3)`:

3 != 0, 5 % 3 = 1 then next call is `gcd(3,1)`.

1 != 0, 3 % 1 = 0 then next call is `gcd(1, 0)`.

0 == 0 then greatest common divisor of 5 and 3 is 1.

Answer (score 0):

An exact equivalent but more clear (to me) code is:

```
function gcd(num1, num2) { 
  if (num2 === 0) return num1;
  else return gcd (num2, num1 % num2);
}
```

Now do a few by hand:

console.log(gcd(15, 6));
num2 (6) is not 0 so return gcd(6, 15%6) or gcd(6,3)
num2 (3) is not 0 so return gcd(3, 6%3) or gcd(3,0)
num2 (0) is now 0 so return 3

console.log(gcd(6, 15));
num2 (15) is not 0 so return gcd(15, 6%15) or gcd(15,6)
num2 (6) is not 0 so return gcd(6, 15%6) or gcd(6,3)
num2 (3) is not 0 so return gcd(3, 6%3) or gcd(3,0)
num2 (0) is now 0 so return 3

Or, you can let the code tell you what's going on:
This is for factorial(n) but you could do the same for gcd():
The important point is that "k" is different for each call:

```
console.log("FINALLY, factorial(5) = ", factorial(5));

function FACTORIAL(num) { // this is without the BS
  if (num == 1) return 1;
  else return num * factorial(num-1);
}
function factorial(num) { // this shows all
  console.log("getting factorial(" + num + ")");
  if (num == 1) {
    console.log("factorial of 1 is just 1");
    return 1;
  } else {
    console.log("need to get factorial(" + (num-1) + ")");
    let k = num * factorial(num - 1);
    console.log("got factorial(" + num + ") = " + k);
    return k;
  }
}
```